# What is the equivalent of std::less for the three-way comparison operator?

Tags: c++, c++20, function-object, spaceship-operator

Does C++20 define something similar to `std::less` for three-way comparison operator (`<=>`).

I would like define some datasructure with customizable comparator as `map` or `unordered_map` do.

```
template <class DefaultComparison = std::??????<Key>,
struct MyContainer ...
```

Comment: @Tommy-XavierRobillard JFI documentation from cppreference.com have 0 mentioning about it on the corresponding page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons But thank you anyway

Comment: @Dewfy I've found it by going std:less -> functional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[std::compare_three_way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/compare_three_way) is what you are looking for.